Try to sync Lists between Clients and Client/Host
I'm using Unity and Netcode for Game Objects. I want to create my own Cardgame, so I want to have a synced Cardlist which is controlled over the Server/Host.
To get started, I wanted to synchronize a list (deck) from which individual clients can remove strings and add them to their list (PlayerCards). The deck should then be synchronized for everyone.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class PlayerNetwork : NetworkBehaviour
{
    //Cards in the Deck to draw
    List<string> Deck = new List<string>();
    //Cards on each Player
    List<string> PlayerCards = new List<string>();

    private void Start()
    {
        Deck.Add("Card1");
        Deck.Add("Card2");
        Deck.Add("Card3");
        Deck.Add("Card4");
        Deck.Add("Card5");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (!IsOwner)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
        {
            CardServerRpc(OwnerClientId);
        }
    }
    [ClientRpc]
    private void UpdateCardsClientRpc()
    {
        Deck.RemoveAt(0);
        Debug.Log("Id:" + OwnerClientId);
    }
    [ClientRpc]
    private void AddCardsToPlayerCardClientRpc(ClientRpcParams clientRpcParams)
    {
        Debug.Log("Id:" + OwnerClientId +"Card:" + Deck[0]);
        PlayerCards.Add(Deck[0]);
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    private void CardServerRpc(ulong index)
    {
        if (Deck.Count >0)
        {
            AddCardsToPlayerCardClientRpc(new ClientRpcParams { Send = new ClientRpcSendParams { TargetClientIds = new List<ulong> { index } } });
            UpdateCardsClientRpc();
        }
    }
}

2 Points:

If I call from a Client a ServerRpc and the ServerRpc calls a ClientRpc and I have 2 Clients, shouldn't a Debug be called twice in the Console? When I press T, I can only see the message in the console from the client I am currently using.
Only the Client I open in Unityeditor, not a build one, is able to Add a Card to the Player

